# What is the keyword for apple sign in, in the firebase security rules language?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

In the custom firebase security rules language, created by Google - what is the keyword used to check if a user was authenticated via Sign In with Apple? The documentation includes “email”, “facebook”, “google”, “github” and “custom” — but not phone number auth or Sign In with Apple.

What are the key words to use for phone number and apple sign in on next codes?

```
if auth.provider == “github || auth.provider == ____ || auth.provider == _____ {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the documentation the auth.provider can contain

> allows you to easily authenticate to several built-in providers and will generate auth tokens for them. After a user is authenticated with one of the built-in providers, the auth variable will contain the following:

> ... (e.g "password", "anonymous", "facebook", "github", "google", or "twitter").

which might mean that apple is not one of them. but you can try "apple" and see if it works

Another option:

You can use **auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider** which can be one of:

- password
- phone
- google.com
- facebook.com
- twitter.com
- github.com
- apple.com
- yahoo.com
- hotmail.com

so you can use that in the rule

Comment: This is useful. The doc of firebase doesn't mention apple. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request